# How to quickly check your mining speed?

Tags: hashpower, mining-hardware, performance, webminer

Is there some website that provides some webminer or other way for a person to check their mining speed without actually joining any pool or doing solo mining? Alternatively, are there some miners that can be pre-configured to perform mining on a specific pool with given credentials?

Or to put it in another way, if I wanted to simplify the process of checking a mining speed of a given computer for someone with minimal knowledge of what Bitcoin is, what websites or software should I use?

Comment: If you've found this question trying to figure out how to **get rich mining from your laptop**, please read: [In the ASIC-age, is it worth starting mining Bitcoin at home?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/41276/5406)

Answer (score 5):

Very good question. Today I created a page at my pool for this purpose: http://bitminter.com/test

You don't get paid without registering and entering a name and password. But it is useful for the purposes you stated in the question. Just click the "test start" button. You need Java installed, and of course GPU drivers with OpenCL support if that's what you want to test.

PS: Thanks for the idea for this.

Comment: Pretty good implementation, although it seems to be mining at about 75% speed of some other miners. Is there some way to pre-set some credentials by altering the .jnlp file?

Comment: At the moment it doesn't run well with the latest AMD drivers. Credentials are usually typed in and saved along with other settings. But this test version runs as a test-user every time.

Comment: I cant see a test button, has it changed :(

Comment: There is a round button with a green light and the text "TEST START". When it asks for a user name type in test. Note that in 2017 the bitcoin hashrate of a GPU doesn't matter as all GPUs are too slow to put a dent in bitcoin mining.

Comment: downloads test.jnlp and errors about cert https://pasteboard.co/GFo2SwY.png

Comment: Yeah, the certificate the app was signed with has expired. But in 2017 your PCs hashrate is essentially zero. It doesn't matter which graphics card you have. You need to buy an ASIC miner.