# Minimal but profitable miner setup with solar energy

Tags: mining-profitability, mining-hardware

Im looking for 20W/h (at 5V) consuming system for running with solar panel. Is it possible with current miners? If you say it will never be profitable I say 5$ for a month is big target for me. The currency can be different than bitcoin. Im so beginner.

Comment: 5$ might be worth it for you, but keep in mind, the expenses to build such miner will probably be 50-100 times that. So before you have earned that back, and top it with 5$....

Comment: Can you give some name of example miners?

Comment: Pretty any miner that runs on linux will do, if you would use the raspberry pi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there were a few USB stick miners very early in the game, rigs have rather gotten bigger than smaller since then.

According to [Mining Hardware Comparison](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison) the smallest rig that is still shipping,  `Antminer U3 Batch 2`, needs 63W.

Its energy efficiency is only one tenth of the current best equipment though, and you'd have to invest at least $40 which you likely would never make back:
[In the ASIC-age, is it worth starting mining Bitcoin at home?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/41276/5406)

Comment: Oh, this was my 500th answer on Bitcoin.SE. Congratulations to myself. ;)