# Bitcoin c++ library that provides the networking

Tags: development, library

I want to make a very simple Bitcoin mining software with use of `getblocktemplate`, my own SHA and block building. Is there any `c` or better `c++` library that would help with the networking part? I am new to Bitcoin and would prefer to focus on the block building and hashing part for now, as I'm starting from scratch.

I'm aware of the difficulty level and I am doing this just for getting to know Bitcoin better.

Comment: When you say miner, do you mean you want to make hardware or software?

Comment: Software, sorry for not making it clear

Comment: So, bad news:  http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/41276/in-the-asic-age-is-it-worth-starting-mining-bitcoin-at-home  If you just want to do this for fun, remember that you won't solve a block within your lifetime, so I don't know how much fun will be had.  Maybe you should focus on just the block building aspect.

Comment: Of course I don't expect this to profitable. But still when I have the mining part done it would be nice to connect to actual network and check whether it works on real-life blocks. Even if it's going to fail every time ;)

Comment: @M-guy: I've edited your question to include the content from your comments, please feel free to edit as you like.