# New To Mining - How Much US$ Am I Making / Day?

Tags: mining-profitability

I am using a GTX 1050 ti SSC with fans at 100%. I got really lucky and this card might be the best overclockable one ever, I boosed performance by about 20%, when other people are happy to get 10%. Anyways, I am using MultiMiner and I am curious how much US$ I will make every 24 hours on average. The difficulty says 440.79B, price is Bitcoin, Profitability says 100%, Average is 386.21 MH/s, and Intensity is D. Thank you for help and is this good or bad?

Comment: also see: [In the ASIC-age, is it worth starting mining Bitcoin at home?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/41276/5406)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, are you trying to mine bitcoin?

And if you are then I am very sorry to tell you but trying to mine with 386.21 MH/s with the current bitcoin difficulty, means that you will mine close to no bitcoin. The power cost will be much higher than the mined bitcoin and thus will be unprofitable.

Currently, I am not aware of any person still trying to mine bitcoin with GPU's, I might be wrong, but the difficulty has gone up so much that it is not profitable anymore.

You can use [this](http://www.bitcoinx.com/profit/) site to check your profitability, but as I said if you're trying to mine bitcoin I don't think you will find it profitable.