# BitMinter Hash rate

Tags: hash, hashpower, bitminter

I checked on BitMinter (https://bitminter.com/) and it says my computational power is 2058Thps, is that a good thing for bitcoin mining, i'm rather new to the mining community and am uncertain. I would also like to know what software would be best to use on my computer, i am using a MSI GE62 Apache Pro.

Answer (score 1):

That 2058 Thps is not your hash power, it's the total hash power of that mining pool.  And even if you have a super-fast computer, it's not worth mining. More info: [In the ASIC-age, is it worth starting mining Bitcoin at home?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/41276/in-the-asic-age-is-it-worth-starting-mining-bitcoin-at-home)