# Can High CPU Droplets from Digital Ocean be used for Bitcoin Mining?

Tags: mining-hardware, gpu-mining, cpu-mining, gpu, cloud-mining

Can the High CPU Droplets from Digital Ocean be used for Bitcoin Mining? Can they compete with GPUs?

[Digital Ocean High CPU Droplets](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/compute/high-cpu/)

Answer (score 3):

No, neither CPUs nor GPUs of any kind are of the slightest use in Bitcoin mining.  This has been the case for several years, since the introduction of ASIC miners which are now many orders of magnitude more efficient.

See [In the ASIC-age, is it worth starting mining Bitcoin at home?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/41276/in-the-asic-age-is-it-worth-starting-mining-bitcoin-at-home?rq=1)

Comment: Correct answer strictly speaking, however it is worth noting that GPU mining is still profitable for many (most) of the other crypto currencies (like XMR)

Comment: Follow up -- At the current point Digital Ocean provides you with 1 Xeon 2.6GHZ CPU per $20 (they have multiple options, but it's 20/CPU) -- Sadly, these are not Quad Core CPU's but single core.  XMR hash rate using stack is roughly 25H/s.  I tried it with the $40/month setup and you'd mine about $2 of XMR per month :( https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/calculator/xmr?HashingPower=53.2&HashingUnit=H%2Fs&PowerConsumption=1000&CostPerkWh=0.06&MiningPoolFee=1

Comment: @BadPirate: Markets are efficient.  You can generally assume that if it were this easy, someone would already have done it, and driven up the difficulty to where they couldn't do it anymore.

Comment: Yeah, I looked into it hoping that it might be at near efficiency levels, creates a way to "purchase" crypto currency without having to participate in an exchange.  However, $40 for $2 worth of currency isn't a really good trade off :)