# How can I find real man for bitcoin mining investment?

Tags: mining-pools, bitcoin-cash, trading, spending

can anyone help me for find a real people? Where I can invest for mining, because i lost lot of money before. Someone scamming with me.
Thanks

Comment: Mining bitcoin requires specialized hardware, and a certain level of technical expertise. Anyone advertising that you can 'invest in mining' with them is almost certainly running a scam. Unless you are purchasing mining hardware (an ASIC machine) to set up and run yourself, you are likely getting scammed, or at least being taken advantage of.

Comment: See [In the ASIC-age, is it worth starting mining Bitcoin at home?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/41276/13866) -- Getting involved in Bitcoin mining is not suitable for anybody who is new to Bitcoin. You will almost certainly lose even more money.

Answer (score 2):

The only real "safe" way to invest in mining is to simply start mining yourself. There are [many](https://www.bitcoinmining.com/getting-started/) [online](https://99bitcoins.com/bitcoin-mining/) [resources](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lAW5fqkL-Fo) for teaching you how to do this. Depending on the price of Bitcoin, [your local electricity](https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/calculator/btc), network difficulty, and the price of your [equipment](https://shop.bitmain.com/?lang=en) your profitability will vary greatly. In most cases it may make sense to just buy and hold the coin and perhaps play around with trading in general.