# Solo Mining With CpuMiner (Guide / Adventure)

Tags: cpuminer

### CpuMiner for Solo Mining Mode Guide.

After you download the ENTIRE blockchain, and you get your bitcoin-core running in Node Mode, just installing the program and allowing it in the firewall, you need to go to the AppData Hidden folder.
Search for the data of the blockchain and then create a config file.
Default location on Windows is `%APPDATA%\Bitcoin`

Create A config file like this, and rename it to (coinbase.conf)

Here there is no pool. And if you hit a block with your CPU and your bandwidth, 100% of the mining reward is available in your wallet.
Some people say that this is like playing the lottery...
Well I don't have anything to lose and I would be learning a bit more about software and sharing great knowledge with the crypto community, please don't be angry with me :C

So ! I started preconfiguring the file.

```
server=1 
rpcuser=user
rpcpassword=1234
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcport=13000
```

I copy it to the folder where I have got the information of the blockchain. I restart the coin base core And then I start my miner to do it on a solo mode.
And I put this.

**C:\Users\Acha\Desktop\pooler-cpuminer-2.5.0-win64>minerd.exe -o localhost:13000 -O user:1234 -t 8 --coinbase-addr=bc1q74nxlgjv8w384gssnxp8evnjlw3utm8zm3ctpe -D --protocol-dump**

And I'm getting some wrong bitcoin invalid address error.

As the ppl said in the post, this is the last compiled version of Cpu miner, and the support for this bitcoin addresses has been incorporated this last year.
The guy behind this is a senior programmer so, maybe he's busy, and he cant compile the new version. Anyway, his job is awesome, and it's under a GNU license.
Thank you. His project named Minerd or Cpuminer it's here:

https://github.com/pooler/cpuminer

Thank you so much, it has a lot of work encoding data structures.

So at this point with the entire source code, and the upgrade of the bech32 addresses I need to recompile the entire thing to run properly on my windows.

The thing is... if it's a C++ program would I be able to open it with visual studio? The answer is who knows.

Then I researched the internet for more information, and the people are giving me 2 pieces of software.
This is the basic windows instructions by "Pooler" at the original project

```
Basic Windows build instructions, using MinGW:
    Install MinGW and the MSYS Developer Tool Kit (http://www.mingw.org/)
        * Make sure you have mstcpip.h in MinGW\include
    If using MinGW-w64, install pthreads-w64
    Install libcurl devel (http://curl.haxx.se/download.html)
        * Make sure you have libcurl.m4 in MinGW\share\aclocal
        * Make sure you have curl-config in MinGW\bin
    In the MSYS shell, run:
        ./autogen.sh    # only needed if building from git repo
        LIBCURL="-lcurldll" ./configure CFLAGS="-O3"
        make
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW#Components

For my surprise the First URL is unavailable,

Then I installed the MSys2
-MSys Software and its a collection of GNU utilities such as bash, make, gawk and grep to allow the building of applications and programs which depend on traditionally UNIX tools to be present. It is intended to supplement MinGW and the deficiencies of the cmd shell. An example would be building a library that uses the autotools build system.

So here I am, launching commands from a little shell/Terminal that maybe can compile the Pooler project,
The commands from the Msys terminal
gcc--version | make--version |git--version

```
pacman -Su
```

Then i close mysys, and open MinGw64

```
pacman -S gcc
pacman -S base-devel
pacman -Syu git make mingw-w64-x86_64-{gcc,cmake,icu,jemalloc,zlib} --force
```

Following this source in youtube.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pb6Yb819pF0

This is where I put the Pooler's project to compile

**C:\msys64\home\Acha\cpuminer-master**

I reached this point. I need some coffee and some gaming, I would try to do something at night here in Spain.
More info about Clone projects

https://github.com/tpruvot/cpuminer-multi
https://github.com/vertoe/cpuminer-cach

Well surfing the web I encountered a clone project of this one but with a longer explanation and guide to set up the version to compile.
Wellcome hell

```
Acha@DESKTOP-9QUABRJ MSYS /c/msys64/home/acha/cpuminer-master
$ ./autogen.sh

Acha@DESKTOP-9QUABRJ MSYS /c/msys64/home/acha/cpuminer-master
$ ./configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 CFLAGS="-O3 -march=native -DCPU_X86_FORCE_INTRINSICS"``
```

Also, the compiler is giving me tons of errors so I'm stuck here, but I will try tomorrow harder again.

```
Acha@DESKTOP-9QUABRJ MSYS /c/msys64/home/acha/cpuminer-master
$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/c/msys64/home/acha/cpuminer-master'
Making all in compat
make[2]: Entering directory '/c/msys64/home/acha/cpuminer-master/compat'
Making all in jansson
make[3]: Entering directory '/c/msys64/home/acha/cpuminer-master/compat/jansson'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/c/msys64/home/acha/cpuminer-master/compat/jansson'
make[3]: Entering directory '/c/msys64/home/acha/cpuminer-master/compat'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/c/msys64/home/acha/cpuminer-master/compat'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/c/msys64/home/acha/cpuminer-master/compat'
make[2]: Entering directory '/c/msys64/home/acha/cpuminer-master'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DCURL_STATICLIB  -I./compat/jansson   -fno-strict-aliasing -O3 -march=native -DCPU_X86_FORCE_INTRINSICS -MT minerd-scrypt.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/minerd-scrypt.Tpo -c -o minerd-scrypt.o `test -f 'scrypt.c' || echo './'`scrypt.c
/tmp/ccGUMY6c.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccGUMY6c.s:59: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
/tmp/ccGUMY6c.s:61: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
/tmp/ccGUMY6c.s:63: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
/tmp/ccGUMY6c.s:65: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
/tmp/ccGUMY6c.s:67: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
/tmp/ccGUMY6c.s:69: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
/tmp/ccGUMY6c.s:71: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
/tmp/ccGUMY6c.s:73: Error: invalid register for .seh_savexmm
make[2]: *** [Makefile:733: minerd-scrypt.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/c/msys64/home/acha/cpuminer-master'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:796: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/msys64/home/acha/cpuminer-master'
make: *** [Makefile:426: all] Error 2
```

I have all the binaries and the code is updated, ty for ur help. I'm so sorry for the other post...if I can help in any way... :( I'll keep u informed in this main topic. But any idea to understand what I'm doing wrong is welcomed as always :3
I hateeeeee linuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuux

***Thanx Etsa***

Comment: Mining on a CPU is a good way to waste money, get no reward for it, and burn out your CPU at the same time. For example see: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/41276/in-the-asic-age-is-it-worth-starting-mining-bitcoin-at-home/41277#41277

Comment: "Black ops"??? And as far as I know, the official [cpuminer](https://github.com/pooler/cpuminer) is not distributed in rar format.  I would be concerned that you may have gotten some malware instead.

Answer (score 4):

Bech32 support was only added to CpuMiner in January, 2019 in [7e8960212f0055d6dafaa3c80812c50cec291de3](https://github.com/pooler/cpuminer/commit/7e8960212f0055d6dafaa3c80812c50cec291de3).

v2.5.0 is a release form 2017, and looks to be the latest precompiled release.

You will need to mine to a p2sh or p2pkh address, or compile a newer version yourself.

In any case, CPU mining bitcoin is a waste of time, you will never see any ROI whatsoever.