# What software should I use to mine bitcoins?

Tags: bitcoin-core, mining-pools, mining-profitability

I'm really interested in bitcoins but I don't really trust any exchanges to keep my ID safe. I thought it would be a good idea to mine bitcoins for a day or two to get a couple of cents to send around to different address and see how it works!

Is this a good plan? Is there a better way? Also what software should I use? I did a little research and thought this looked good! https://github.com/luke-jr/bfgminer

Comment: First you need mining hardware; with just software you won't mine any BTC (in order of a few USD cents per year, if you have a good graphics card...).

Comment: Oh! So a AMD Radeon rx 470 won't get me *anything* for a long long time? Again I'm not trying to earn any cash I'm just curious on how it all works and want just enough to cover a transfer fee! Thanks!

Comment: You can read a bit more why you'd be unable to earn anything with household hardware here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/41276/5406

Comment: @piggy "a long long time" is more like *not even a cent in a trillion years*

Comment: Ok thanks everyone! I just though it would just be unprofitable because of electricity costs and not "You won't earn any money because you'll never be able to cash out"!