# Recommendation for educational mining

Tags: mining-hardware, miner-configuration, bfgminer

I've been running a full `bitcoind` node (Ubuntu) for a while now and would like to experiment with mining for educational purposes.

Googling anything to do with "Bitcoin mining" is fraught so I was hoping some more informed user can sanity check my plans.

I was going to buy a 20-40 G/H USB ASIC, plug that into the node and run BFGMiner on the same system, using its solo-mining configuration to communicate with my `bitcoind` RPC service.

Is this a good way to proceed? If not, any other recommendation would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Garreth, your question might be covered by https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/41276/5406, check it out!

Comment: It doesn't. My interest is educational.

Comment: Well what do you want to learn about? There are many aspects to mining; the protocols used, the hardware available, infrastructure and maintenance, latency aspects, economics of it all, ... how to learn about those will depend on what you're interested in.

Comment: I basically just want to know that buying something like a Gekkoscience USB miner and running it with something like BFGMiner of GGMiner will work. These are essentially legacy technologies at this point, and I don't want to waste $70.