# What happens to the bitcoin mining if the device changes?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, client, buy-bitcoins

First I've opened this site via mobile and registered with a Google account. Some time later, I continued to mine bitcoin through my laptop with the same account. Will this device change make it impossible for me to exchange the earned bitcoins to dollar or other currencies?

Comment: You cannot mine bitcoins with a laptop or mobile phone. Which site are you talking about? What makes you think that the website is mining Bitcoin when you log in?

Comment: https://cryptofree.casa/dashboard     this is the site im talking about. It refers this Website to ask any other questions.

Comment: @Ramtin that site is obviously a scam of some sort, mining requires highly specialized hardware. It is not possible on a phone / laptop / etc.

Comment: Some people say they could earn about 7 or 10 grand. So u think this is not true?

Comment: @Ramtin that is absolutely, without any doubt whatsoever, not true.

Comment: You can read more about the specialized hardware required for mining here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/41276/5406

Answer (score 1):

> Will this device change make it impossible for me to exchange the earned bitcoins to dollar

No, it will make no difference whatsoever to your ability to exchange earned bitcoins to dollars.

However this is because all websites offering Bitcoin mining with mobile phones or laptops are scams which have no intention of ever giving you the Bitcoins they have tricked you into thinking you have earned.

Criminals don't care what changes of computer their victims make.

They might use it as a convenient excuse to blame you for not being able to give you your "earnings" but they'd have easily invented some other excuse if you hadn't made any change.

---

As others have noted

- The difficulty of mining Bitcoin has increased hugely year on year.
- It became infeasible to mine Bitcoin on laptops many many years ago. You now need nearly-free electricity and the equivalent power of tens or hundreds of thousands of laptops to have any chance of profit.
- It has never been possible to mine Bitcoins on smartphones.