# Simple Python code miner which automatically mines and stops

Tags: python, mining-software, solo-mining

I'm new at BTC mining and I'm still learning. I'm almost medium level in Python.

I'm looking for a Python miner that automatically mines using the last block and stops when a new block is found and if I'm lucky, the algorithm adds the new block to the blockchain and sends the prize to a specific wallet address that I can add.

But now for days I'm still looking and nothing.

I find a simple one, it keeps looking, but even if it finds a new block I don't know how to add that to the blockchain, and I don't know if the last block has been changed or not.

Is there any Python algorithm that do all of that, or a few lines of Python code which I can change?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In the ASIC-age, is it worth starting mining Bitcoin at home?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/41276/in-the-asic-age-is-it-worth-starting-mining-bitcoin-at-home)

Comment: thank you for the answer it contains a lot of useful information, but no it did not answer my question I'm looking for a python code that I can modify and it run automatically (get the last block, mine, if I'm lucky it add the block to the block chain, and send price to a specific wallet address)

Comment: I think the point that RedGrittyBrick was making is that you will never find a block mining with a regular computer. Today, you need ASICs to stand a chance to find a block in a conceivable time.

Comment: thank you very much, yes I red the ASIC's article and am looking to learn how to do it with python just for fun if I want to really mine, I will mine another coin, just to learn how to do it and how to make it automatically work, if there is any python ago, or a few hint or an old article because I'm trying to find it for day's now and I find nothing, and thank's again for your help

Answer (score 1):

here is an easy hashminer

```python
from hashlib import sha256
MAX_NONCE = 100000000000

def SHA256(text):
    return sha256(text.encode("ascii")).hexdigest()

def mine(block_number, transactions, previous_hash, prefix_zeros):
    prefix_str = '0'*prefix_zeros
    for nonce in range(MAX_NONCE):
        text = str(block_number) + transactions + previous_hash + str(nonce)
        new_hash = SHA256(text)
        if new_hash.startswith(prefix_str):
            print(f"Yay! Successfully mined bitcoins with nonce value:{nonce}")
            return new_hash

    raise BaseException(f"Couldn't find correct has after trying {MAX_NONCE} times")

if __name__=='__main__':
    transactions='''
    Dhaval->Bhavin->20,
    Mando->Cara->45
    '''
    difficulty=4 # try changing this to higher number and you will see it will take more time for mining as difficulty increases
    import time
    start = time.time()
    print("start mining")
    new_hash = mine(5,transactions,'0000000xa036944e29568d0cff17edbe038f81208fecf9a66be9a2b8321c6ec7', difficulty)
    total_time = str((time.time() - start))
    print(f"end mining. Mining took: {total_time} seconds")
    print(new_hash)
```