# Hello, I'm not new to crypto, but I am quite new to Mining, can someone give me some tips on the best BTC miner as of today?

Tags: blockchain, security, mining-profitability

I am quite afraid of all the things I read on the internet, in seems that there are quite a bit of scams going on and the whole space, specifically crypto mining is quite uncertain.
Anyway, I was hoping someone can give me some good websites, that they know are not scammy and maybe some tips on what I should be looking at if I want to start investing in mining equipment ?

Comment: What do you mean by "investing in mining equipment" exactly? Do you want to buy mining hardware? Do you have a place to set it up and operate it? What do you want the websites to do for you exactly?

Comment: What I meant, is I wanted to invest in ASIC mining machines that mine BTC and I am looking for sites that are not the direct manufacturer, where I can still buy the equipment.

Answer (score 1):

Any website for mining Bitcoin directly is scammy. You need expensive specialised hardware to mine Bitcoin.

The best known supplier of mining equipment is perhaps Bitmain.

See [In the ASIC-age, is it worth starting mining Bitcoin at home?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/41276/13866)