# How can i write my own bitcoin miner software/program?

Tags: mining-software

I want to produce satoshis from the computer's cpu or gpu, collect them in a pool and transfer them to the wallet I want. I've been searching for months, but I couldn't find a training set for what I want. My question to you=

Is there any training set that you know of so that I can code my own bitcoin mining program, paid or free?

Comment: It's infeasible to mine Bitcoin with CPUs or GPUs: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/41276/5406

Answer (score 1):

This is a very technical and specific issue. I believe you can't find something like that. But, you can inspect other mining softwares and understand them. After you understand them, you can write your own mining software.

Comment: It is not possible for me to write my own mining application by reviewing a mining software. I need to understand what the codes mean, so I need a training set.

Comment: How do you think to code software without understanding it? No one can explain everything.