# Bitcoin mining on android

Tags: mining-pools

Most Bitcoin mining sites on Android either shut down or become unable to withdraw after a while.
Could there be a real mining site on android or is there a functioning one yet?

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/41276/5406

Answer (score 3):

> **Could there be a real mining site on android**

No, because

- You can't mine Bitcoin using a mobile phone.
- Websites offering to mine Bitcoin for you are all scams (with only a tiny tiny room for doubt).

Answer (score -1):

It is too late to mine bitcoin unless you have mining rig that hashes at at least 100 TH and can afford 2.5 kW/h.electricity costs, and can afford to hold your coin for about 5-10 years. Just saying approximately

Comment: Hey Ive been mining bitcoin from September 2012 to May 2020. If you disagree with my comment say so and give a reason. Dont just down vote bc you think you knew better, which you may but I donr think so.

Comment: Hi user209474, our site is a bit different than a forum or reddit. It is a question & answer platform and our goal is to collect a large body of canonical knowledge. Please check out our [tour] to get a sense of what we are about here. Our [section on “Answering”](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in our help may also be interesting to you.