# Is mining Bitcoin on costumers machine a financially viable plan?

Tags: mining-theory, mining-profitability, business

I don't know if it is the right spot to post but my post has been removed from Reddit so...

I am currently exploring an idea on which I would like to gather your insights and opinions. The idea involves offering services in exchange for the light mining of Bitcoin on users' devices, rather than resorting to direct payments or advertising. I am wondering if this could be a viable and ethical alternative to conventional monetization.

**Advantages:**

Monetization without direct fees: Users could benefit from services without having to pay directly or be exposed to intrusive advertisements.

Consent and transparency: The idea is to obtain explicit consent from users while ensuring complete transparency about how their computing resources are used.

**Disadvantages:**

Risk of negative perception: User reaction is a major concern, and I am seeking to understand whether the idea would be well-received or not.

User machine capabilities: The capabilities of users' machines are the second major concern.

**My questions:**

Legality and ethics: How do you perceive the idea of using users' computing resources for light Bitcoin mining in exchange for services? Is it ethical and legal as long as consent is obtained?

User Perception: Do you think users would be comfortable with the idea of their devices being used for mining, even if it's light?

Technological complexities: What could be the main technological complexities related to implementing this approach while maintaining a satisfactory user experience? Is it feasible to mine around five dollars per month on a personal machine?

I am open to any suggestions or criticisms you may have in this area.

I have limited knowledge in mining and am a developer, so feel free to be specific.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In the ASIC-age, is it worth starting mining Bitcoin at home?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/41276/in-the-asic-age-is-it-worth-starting-mining-bitcoin-at-home)

Answer (score 3):

This is a bad idea for multiple reasons.

1. Consumer hardware is entirely useless for Bitcoin mining today. You will never make a cent. See e.g. [In the ASIC-age, is it worth starting mining Bitcoin at home?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/41276/5406)
2. Most consumer hardware is not designed for continuous load. Mining might brick your users’ devices.
3. Most users will click through any agreement without reading it, so getting actual consent may be neigh impossible, but they will be quite upset when they figure out why their device is slower and their electricity bill is higher than expected